# How to find correlation among numerical, categorical (MCQ-Single Response) and (MCQ-Multiple Response)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, correlation, categorical-data

I have a dataset of a questionnaire with numerical, MCQ-Single Response and MCQ-Multiple Response.There are 22 columns in total. The dataset looks something like this:

```
Age    ChooseTransport   WillgobyTrain  ....
52      1011001                 2
21      1000100                 1
25      1110000                 1
46      0001000                -1
32      1000001                 2
```

'Age' is a numerical variable. 'ChooseTransport' is MCQ- Multiple response with 7 choices, where 1 stands for the user has chosen that choice and 0 if not chosen. 'WillgobyTrain' is a MCQ-Single Response and has the choice number.

I would like to find the correct measure to find the correlation among these different types of variables.

Comment: I would like to write the code in Python rather than R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should split `ChooseTransport` into 7 colunms then try to use  `data.corr()` (if your data is a `pandas.DataFrame`).

For splitting `ChooseTransport` try this:

```
for row_index, answer in enumerate(data['ChooseTransport']):
    for i in range(7):
        name = 'ChooseTransport_' + str(i)
        data.loc[row_index, name] = int(answer[i])
```

Then drop old column `ChooseTransport`:

```
data.drop(columns=['ChooseTransport'], inplace=True)
```

Finally use `data.corr()`:

```
data.corr()
```

For visualisation use `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(data.corr())
```

Comment: Thanks. But is that the correct measure of finding correlation between questions?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe Spearman rank correlation is more conforming than Pearson correlation (`data.corr(method='spearman')`).

Comment: @Kuhu Gupta, if my answer was useful to you, consider upvoting and accepting it according to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)